# Cant import Sun openGL

Tags: opengl, java, jogl

I've been working with JOGL and I've ran into a problem. The problem is when I try to import `import com.sun.opengl.*;` on Eclipse, Eclipse doesn't recognize it. Does anyone know where this library is? Did I miss a step during installation? I'm working with the latest build.

Here are the included libraries:

- gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar - JOGL/lib
- gluegen-rt - JOGL/lib
- gluegen.jar - JOGL/lib
- jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar - JOGL/lib
- jogl-all.jar - JOGL/lib

This is within my JOGL project folder:

- gluegen-rt.dll

Comment: This sounds suspiciously "too localized" to me, but you need to provide more details. At the very least, an actual error message because "Eclipse doesn't recognize it" could mean a variety of things.

Comment: @JoshPetrie It says "The import com.sun.opengl cannot be resolved"

Comment: I had good luck using: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/JOGL2.0.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for. A separate jar file located here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjogl20jar.htm

Answer (score 3):

SUN/Oracle are not maintaining JOGL 1 since 2009.
http://labb.zafena.se/?p=656 - The JogAmp community now maintains JOGL 2 and Java3D.

Casses found under com.sun.opengl.* are now found under com.jogamp.opengl.* in JogAmp JOGL 2.

If you want to use JOGL that support both mobile, tablets and desktops then its recommended to migrate your code to JOGL 2 that is well maintained and got better support for all new shader based GPU OpenGL profiles. http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html